# Restrict "add more" button to add new fieldset after adding 5 fieldsets

Tags: entities

I have taken a field of type field collection in my user-profile-form and its cardinality is set to unlimited as I wanted to have "add more" button for the users. I want to restrict the addition of fieldset to five numbers.

If I change the number of fields to be displayed to 5 from edit, it renders all the five fieldsets altogether which I do not want.

I tried overriding field_multiple_value_form() in my template.php file but did not succeeded. Please suggest some ideas to achieve this.
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using css. First of all write `hook_form_alter()` on your custom module. and your code should be like this..

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
    if (isset($form['your_field']['und']['#max_delta']) && $form['your_field']['und']['#max_delta'] == 4) {
      $form['your_field']['und']['add_more']['#prefix'] = '';
      $form['your_field']['und']['add_more']['#suffix'] = '';    
    }
  }
}
```

Where `$form['your_field']` is your field collection field machine name. You can write your custom css on #prefix and #suffix and set it to display none.
[image: you can set display none to wrapper div element]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this module [Multivalue Settings](https://www.drupal.org/project/multivalue_settings)

> This module adds some useful settings for fields that can contain
>   multiple values. You can specify:
>
> Number of values allowed Number of values required Number of empty
>   widgets to display initially (Drupal usually displays all fields for
>   non-unlimited fields. This allows you to only display a few, followed
>   by the 'Add More' button, which will disappear after the maximum
>   number of fields has been filled.) Number of empty widgets to display
>   on edit forms after the field contains some values (Drupal usually
>   displays one extra)

I had tested and worked well for me. But please use this module at your own risk, as the module owner himself said that its quite buggy.